# How to convert, cast, or add '$' to a decimal SQL SUM()

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

What's the simple way to add the dollar sign ('$') or currency to a decimal data type on the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 100000  
        SUM ([dbo].[Entry].[Amount]) AS 'Total Charges'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Simplest and best way is to do it outside of the database on whatever is displaying the information.

Comment: As Michael says, this is best done in the presentation layer. However, if for some reason you absolutely need to do it through SQL then you should specify which SQL product (and version) you are using as these sorts of manipulations are often dependent on the particular vendor's implementation of SQL.

Comment: @Michael & Tom, Thanks for the comments and guidance. I'm doing it at the application layer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just presenting concern and should be done in application layer.

But `SQL Server` can do it using [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM ([Amount]), 'c', 'en-US') AS 'Total Charges'
FROM Entry
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417400)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════╗
║  Total Charges  ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ $21.00          ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. I couldn't do it at the application layer because it's presented in a Gridview and I'm not sure if this can be done there too.

Comment: @Jacman It absolutely can, you just have to specify the format for each column instead of blindly showing the results from the SQL layer.

Comment: @Stanley thanks! I did it under DataFormatString  with {0:C} format. I guess this way saves the trouble of executing it at sql level.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using Sql Server 2012

```
Declare @Currency float = 1500.00

Select Format(@Currency, 'C', 'en-US')
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t mind about the output datatype then you can convert the result to varchar and append the '$'.

```
SELECT TOP 100000 
 '$ ' + convert(varchar(10), SUM ([dbo].[Entry].[Amount])) AS 'Total Charges'
```